# React Native Twilio Android Errors

Tags: android, react-native, twilio, twilio-api

I've been trying to debug this for a while but can't come up with anything.

The app uses [this](https://github.com/rogchap/react-native-twilio) react native twilio library.

Everything works great on iOS, but in Android, after creating a call, I get what looks like an infinite loop stating the following errors:

`01-04 17:54:34.430 8477-8617/com.channelmobile D/PJSIP: 17:54:34.430     resolver.c !Received 109 bytes DNS response from 10.0.2.3:53
01-04 17:54:34.465 8477-9329/com.channelmobile D/PJSIP: 17:54:34.465          speex !warning: Had to discard a playback frame (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
01-04 17:54:34.491 8477-8617/com.channelmobile D/PJSIP: 17:54:34.431     resolver.c  Nameserver 10.0.2.3:53 state changed Active --> Active
01-04 17:54:34.518 8477-9329/com.channelmobile D/PJSIP: 17:54:34.518          speex !warning: Had to discard a playback frame (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
01-04 17:54:34.523 8477-9329/com.channelmobile D/PJSIP: 17:54:34.523          speex  warning: Had to discard a playback frame (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
01-04 17:54:34.549 8477-8617/com.channelmobile D/PJSIP: 17:54:34.491     resolver.c !DNS response from 10.0.2.3:53 id=3 discarded
01-04 17:54:34.558 8477-9329/com.channelmobile D/PJSIP: 17:54:34.558          speex  warning: Had to discard a playback frame (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
01-04 17:54:34.558 8477-9329/com.channelmobile D/PJSIP: 17:54:34.558          speex  warning: Had to discard a playback frame (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
01-04 17:54:34.562 8477-9329/com.channelmobile D/PJSIP: 17:54:34.562          speex  warning: Had to discard a playback frame (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
01-04 17:54:34.609 8477-9329/com.channelmobile D/PJSIP: 17:54:34.609          speex  warning: Had to discard a playback frame (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
01-04 17:54:34.613 8477-9329/com.channelmobile D/PJSIP: 17:54:34.613          speex  warning: Had to discard a playback frame (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
01-04 17:54:34.664 8477-9329/com.channelmobile D/PJSIP: 17:54:34.664          speex  warning: Had to discard a playback frame (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
01-04 17:54:34.669 8477-9329/com.channelmobile D/PJSIP: 17:54:34.669          speex  warning: Had to discard a playback frame (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
01-04 17:54:34.681 8477-9330/com.channelmobile D/PJSIP: 17:54:34.681          speex !warning: No playback frame available (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
01-04 17:54:34.681 8477-9330/com.channelmobile D/PJSIP: 17:54:34.681          speex  warning: No playback frame available (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
01-04 17:54:34.682 8477-9330/com.channelmobile D/PJSIP: 17:54:34.682          speex  warning: No playback frame available (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
01-04 17:54:34.682 8477-9330/com.channelmobile D/PJSIP: 17:54:34.682          speex  warning: No playback frame available (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)`

The error gets thrown when the call is initiated:

`Twilio.connect({ To: '+61234567890' })`

Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: What code are you using to create the connection?

Comment: Just updated the question to show the code that is throwing the error @MeganSpeir

Comment: Is it possible that you provide some more lines of code, e.g. initialization, or an empty react-native app that uses same codes as yours to use as playground would be nice.

Comment: Does it happen when user hang up call ?

Comment: The same errors continue to be thrown, but the call does indeed end.

Comment: That's because timing is wrong or approximative in your connection. Try waiting a second after the connection (not saying it is a solution but can help identify the issue)